# What's the actual probability of an event occurring predicted by a classification model?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability, supervised-learning

I have a classification model that predicts whether event A will occur or event B. The accuracy of the model is 49%. Say for a test case it predicts that event A will occur with a probability of 72%. So what is the probability that Event A will occur?

Comment: Is this homework? If so please explain your difficulty.

Comment: It's not a homework. It's a personal project of mine. I am predicting whether a home team will win a match or whether an away team will win a match. I am training a  gradient boosting classifier model which gives a 49% accuracy on test data.

Comment: you seem to have a bit of confusion about probabilities: this is binary classification, where events A and B are complement of each other: p(B)=1-p(A). (1) a model which obtains less than 50% accuracy in binary classification is bad, because a random model would reach 50% (a majority baseline model might reach higher performance). (2) the probability predicted by the model for event A is a *prediction*, i.e. it might be accurate or completely wrong. In other words there's no way to deduce the real probability from just one instance.

Comment: Btw SO is for programming questions only, this kind of question would fit better at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.